# Firebase Hosting Webhooks

Tags: firebase, github, webhooks, firebase-hosting, gridsome

I have this specific use case that I'm trying to solve with Firebase Hosting and it's the following:

1. I'm using Gridsome to generate static websites
2. **Before building**, Gridsome uses Graphql and grabs from a Headless CMS some blog posts, which then are used to create static pages for each of them
3. Currently, the Gridsome build is automatically deployed to Firebase Hosting whenever I merge into master through Github (this works great already)

The problem that I'm facing is that I want to trigger a Gridsome build + Firebase Hosting deploy whenever I publish a new blog post on my Headless CMS (It has the option to make a POST on new blog post). I know this is possible on other solutions like [Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/more/deploy-hooks), but right now I'm using Firebase and would like to stick to the suite.

I've tried using the REST API without any luck, and [Github Webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks) works the other way around and doesn't solve my problem. I'm thinking there might be a chance to call a Firebase function and use the CLI to deploy or something.

What I would like to know is if this feature exists and how to accomplish this scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Firebase Functions? You can create an HTTP function that can be called by sending an HTTP request to it. Then, you could probably setup a webhook with your CMS that points to that function. I'm unsure if they can then trigger your site to rebuild, but they might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Github Actions to build your project and then deploy it to firebase.

The easiest solution that I would recommend for you is to set up your Action to trigger not only on a push into your master branch, but also for a request.

### Steps

Set your Action trigger for the `repository_dispatch` Event

```
on:
  repository_dispatch:
```

Then create an [Access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) for your Github Account with `repo` and `workflow` permission.

Now you just have to set your CMS Post Request on the following URL `https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo>/dispatches` with your Authorization Token in the Header.

Example:

```
curl --url 'https://api.github.com/repos/<USERNAME>/<REPO>/dispatches' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
  --data '{"event_type": "content updated"}'
```

Now your Action should also dispatch whenever you make a POST Request from your CMS to the endpoint.